# word for things that you want one more of

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word for things which you always one more of? like chips, or beer, or civilization V?

I thought maybe compulsive, but it doesn't seem right in a sentce "Chips are so compulsive!" or "Beer is so compulsive! I can't ever have only one!"

Comment: *addictive*. Or [Lay's](https://youtu.be/9IdxwpT061I)

Comment: I agree with Kevin.  In fact I have used "addictive" in that way many times.  "These chips are so addictive, I can't stop eating them!"  Or "Civ V is so addictive.  I played for 10 hours straight yesterday."

Comment: I would use 'moreish' (of food, not a game, which I assume your third example is).

Comment: Kate's *moreish* is closer than you're going to get elsewhere…